# Postgres policy different access for insert vs select

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to create a table where you can insert into provided that the user_id matches your user_id but any one can select any thing.

What I have is the following but its not working. It just restricts the select to the insert policy.

```
CREATE TABLE api.likes (
    id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    "api.items_id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "api.users_id" uuid DEFAULT request.user_id() NOT NULL,
    data jsonb
)

alter table api.likes enable row level security

CREATE POLICY policy_likes_select
    ON api.likes
    FOR select
    TO web_anon 

CREATE POLICY policy_likes_insert
    ON api.likes
    FOR insert
    TO web_anon
    WITH CHECK (
      "api.users_id" = current_setting('request.jwt.claim.user_id')::uuid
    )
```

Comment: Why, why, why would you create a field called `api.items_id`? That's the real issue here.

Comment: Renamed those fields and that did not give the result i was looking for.

Comment: lol of course, that has nothing to do with the policy issue (which is something I don't know about so can't help), I mean it's bizarre and confusing to call a field "x.y", given a dot is used as a separator between table name/alias and field, or schema and table. Fields should ideally be named with with only alphabetic characters, and underscores to separate words.